# Qui détermine l'orthographe et la prononciation des noms propres étrangers?

Tags: traduction, prononciation, orthographe, noms-propres

Depuis quelques jours, le Colonel Kadhafi fait la une des journaux mondiaux.  En anglais, c'est orthographié Gadhafi (CNN) ou Gaddafi (BBC) et, dans les pays francophones, par Kadhafi.  L'arabe se prononce [ainsi](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Ar-Muammar_al-Qaddafi.ogg).
Je pense aussi à [Mikhaël Gorbatchev](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Ru-Mikhail_Sergeyevich_Gorbachev.ogg) (français).

Quelle autorité décide de l'orthographe française ?  Est-ce basé sur la prononciation ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pour les langues d'écriture non latine, il existe des systèmes de [translittération](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translitt%C3%A9ration) ou de transcription qui spécifient une manière de retranscrire les mots en écriture latine. Il peut exister plusieurs systèmes pour la même langue, ce qui conduit à des variantes orthographiques en français. Les systèmes de transcription ont tendance à refléter la prononciation d'origine, mais la correspondance est quelquefois ténue lorsque les langues ont des systèmes phonologiques très différents (par exemple, entre le chinois et le français). À ces variations s'ajoute le fait que les personnes qui retranscrivent des noms propres ne respectent pas toujours des systèmes existants.

معمر القذافي (Mouammar Kadhafi, Kadafi, Kaddafi, Qaddafi, Qadhafi, Ghadafi, Ghaddafi, et j'en passe) est connu pour le très grand nombre d'orthographes différentes que l'on trouve pour son nom. Il y a un peu moins de variations sur Михаил Сергеевич Горбачёв (Mikhaïl Gorbatchev, Gorbatchov, Gorbatchef, et quelques autres).

Il n'y a pas d'autorité qui régisse la transcription des noms de personnes. C'est d'ailleurs quelquefois un problème pour les voyageurs qui se retrouvent avec des transcriptions différentes sur leurs différents documents administratifs (passeport, visa, permis divers, ...).

Pour les noms de lieux, d'autres facteurs entrent en jeu. Certains noms ont leur vie en tant que nom propre français, bien distincte de la vie du nom dans le pays. On n'appelle par exemple jamais *London* la capitale du Royaume-Uni en français (Londres), ou *New Orleans* la plus grande ville de Louisiane (La Nouvelle-Orléans), ou *Köln* la plus grande ville de Rhénanie-du-Nord-Westphalie (Cologne).

Il arrive que des pays souhaitent revenir sur la transcription d'un nom en langue étrangère ; par exemple [Pékin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9kin#Transcriptions) est une transcription basée sur une prononciation ancienne et qui a subi une certaine francisation ; [Canton](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_%28Chine%29) provient d'une transcription du nom de la province ( 广东, Guǎngdōng) et non de celui de la ville (广州 , Guǎngzhōu). Cela n'empêche pas ces noms d'être utilisés par le [gouvernement français](http://www.ambafrance-cn.org/accueil.html?lang=fr) ; la Belgique préfère [Pékin](http://www.diplomatie.be/beijingfr/) et [Guangzhou](http://www.diplomatie.be/guangzhoufr/). L'ONU a choisi Beijing en français, et la Commission de toponymie du Québec [recommande Beijing](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/chroniques-toponymiques/semaine_2008_07_31_2.html) tout en admettant que « dans le cas des noms de lieux, les points de vue du toponymiste et du linguiste sont parfois différents ».

La transcription des noms de lieux peut avoir des implications politiques, soit qu'une transcription évoque un passé colonial avec lequel le pays indépendant veut rompre, soit que le nom ait été transcrit de l'une des langues locales et qu'une autre langue locale ait pris aujourd'hui le dessus. Par exemple [Bombay](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombay#.C3.89tymologie) est arrivé en français par le portugais ; le nom portugais viendrait quant à lui soit d'une expression portugaise (*Bom Bahia*), soit du nom hindi (*Bambai*). Le gouvernement local actuel pousse le nom *Mumbai*, transcription plus directe du marathi. Plusieurs villes d'Inde, dont également [Calcutta](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcutta#Toponymie), ont ainsi changé de nom officiel en anglais.

Ces conflits de nommage peuvent dépasser la simple transcription. Par exemple, dans le cas de [Madras (Chennai)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chennai#Names), le nom datant de l'époque coloniale et le nom local actuel n'ont clairement pas une racine commune. Il y a aussi plusieurs pays dont le nom est contesté pour des raisons politiques. Pour rester sur un cas où les deux noms conservent un lien étymologique, prenons le [pays dont la capitale est Minsk](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi%C3%A9lorussie#Toponymie). Son nom officiel en [France](http://www.ambafrance-by.org/spip.php?article38), en [Belgique](http://consulbel.at.tut.by/fr.html) et au Québec¹ est Biélorussie. En revanche, le pays lui-même demande à être appelé Belarus, ou un nom avoisinant tel que Bélarus en français. Il y a donc une [ambassade du Bélarus en France](http://www.france.belembassy.org/frn), mais une [ambassade de France en Biélorussie](http://france.mfa.gov.by/fr/)). À l'ONU, dont le français est une langue officielle, le pays membre s'appelle [Bélarus](http://www.un.org/depts/dhl/dhlf/unms/belarus.shtml). C'est également le mot utilisé en [Suisse](http://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/fr/home/reps/eur/vblr/afobel.html) et au [Canada](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/poland-pologne/index.aspx?lang=fra&view=d). L'enjeu n'est pas que linguistique, mais aussi historique : la forme *Biélorussie* est une transcription du russe et fait référence à la [Russie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russie) (Расія/Россия) tandis que *Bélarus* est une transcription du biélorusse et fait référence à la [Rus'](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tymologie_de_Rus_et_de_ses_d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9s) (Русь). On retrouve des enjeux similaires autour de la [Birmanie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birmanie) (France, Canada) aussi appelée Myanmar (ONU, Suisse).

¹ 
<sub>C'est en tout cas ce qu'affirment plusieurs sources secondaires, mais je ne trouve pas de confirmation officielle.</sub>

Comment: J'aurais ajouté l'example le plus connu : Birmanie/Myanmar.

Answer (score 9):

L'orthographe de noms étrangers a différentes sources:

- une longue tradition (qui peut avoir sa source dans un des points suivants)
- l'orthographe de la langue source
- un approximation phonétique
- un système de translittération (c.-à.-d. une transformation mécanique de l'orthographe étrangère — souvent dans un alphabet étranger — en une orthographe en alphabet latin).  Il y a souvent plusieurs systèmes concurrents (exemple pour le chinois, les Français en ont un, les Anglais un autre et les Chinois le leur ; la tendance actuelle est d'utiliser le système Chinois d'où « Beijing »  qui remplace « Pékin »).

Comment: Ça s'écrit *Beijing*.

Answer (score 4):

Dans le cas de [Pékin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9kin), l'ortographe usuelle a été recommandée par une certaine [Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_terminologie_et_de_n%C3%A9ologie), et [publiée](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000019509867&dateTexte=) au [Journal officiel de la République française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_officiel_de_la_R%C3%A9publique_fran%C3%A7aise).

Pour Kadhafi, par contre, ça ne nous aide pas.