# Pourquoi devrait-on dire handball à l'allemande ?

Tags: prononciation, emprunts

J'ai la malheureuse habitude de dire handball comme football (qui rime avec La Baule).

Les gens me reprennent souvent en me disant

> On dit hand-balle! C'est Allemand.

Ce à quoi j'ai maintenant pris l'habitude de leur répondre

> Est-ce que je t'emmerde avec paëlla ?

Qui, si on suit la même logique devrait se prononcer quelque chose comme pa-é-ya.

Si vous avez d'autres exemples de mots qui respectent ou ne respectent pas leur langue d'origine, je suis preneur.

Comment: *Chorizo* : si souvent entendu prononcé à l'italienne…

Comment: @cadrian. c'est comment, la prononciation italienne de *chorizo*? Moi, je le prononce comme l'on fait en espagnol, même si je suis italienne...

Comment: @Paola : à l'italienne : /korizo/ ou même /koridzo/ — en espagnol /tʃoriθo/

Comment: Pour les informaticiens, on prononce Integer \ˈinteɡœʁ\ au lieu de l'anglais \ˈintijər\

Comment: BMW, prononcé Bé-èm-vé en France, Bé-èm-wé en Belgique. Désolé je ne sais pas écrire en phonétique...

Comment: @LaurentS. en france on dit plutôt Bé-èm-double-vé mais bon exemple !

Comment: "sweatshirt" est souvent prononcé par les français comme si c'était "sweet shirt".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec le fait qu'il « *faille* respecter » la prononciation originale. À commencer parce que le plus souvent, on ne connait simplement pas les bons phonèmes.

- Dans les langues où je connais l'original, il arrive que j'essaie de me forcer à l'employer, mais le plus souvent, j'imite naturellement la prononciation de mes interlocuteurs, sans trop de préférence personnelle.
- Dans les langues où je ne saurais de toutes façons pas prononcer l'original (correctement), je ne vois aucune raison de me forcer à essayer, en allant à l'encontre d'une autre prononciation courante. Et comme [dit](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4448/1514) Evpok avec raison, chacun fait comme il l'entend.

Je prononce donc plutôt *handball* comme *football*, là encore sauf avec des gens qui disent *hand-balle*, auquel cas je me laisse copier.

---

Pour des exemples :

- *Spaghetti*, *puzzle*, *et cætera*, *nada*, *patio*, *guerilla*, *nickel*...
- N'importe quoi qui vient d'une langue avec un accent tonique, puisque le français ne connait pas ça.
- Tous les *étrangicismes*, en gros.

[Les noms propres étrangers doivent-ils être prononcés à la française ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/les-noms-propres-etrangers-doivent-ils-etre-prononces-a-la-francaise) et [Qui détermine l'orthographe et la prononciation des noms propres étrangers?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/605/qui-determine-lorthographe-et-la-prononciation-des-noms-propres-etrangers) bien que concernant les noms propres, semblent à peu près aussi "illogiques" que ce que tu mentionnes et t'intéressent peut-être.

Comment: Mais pourquoi tant de respect pour un mot d'origine Allemande ? D'autres exemples où les gens sont convaincus qu'il faille les prononcer comme au pays d'origine ?

Comment: Et au deuxième commentaire : n'importe quel mot dont une personne apprend l'origine et découvre qu'elle peut vouloir imposer l'"original" à ses proches est un bon candidat. Le fait que ça soit plus fréquent/prononcé avec l'allemand, si même c'est le cas, a peut-être à voir avec leur rigueur, i.e. les espagnols s'en tamponnent, et pour les anglicismes, c'est déjà une cause perdue. J'ai traversé de lourds débats sur *puzzle* et *chorizo*, si tu veux des exemples de vraies controverses de boulevard.

Comment: Si 'guerilla' est en Espagnol, on doit plutôt écrire 'guerrilla', avec deux "r".

Comment: @yms Et si guérilla venait du français, ça serait aussi le cas, non ? Guerre, guerrier, ...

Comment: Cela me paraît raisonnable. Ce qui est (peut-être) à éviter est de reprendre les amis de façon dogmatique. Après tout, une langue sert (aussi) à communiquer !

Answer (score 10):

Le problème principal avec prononcer *handball* [ɑ̃dbol] c'est que ça ne correspond à rien en français à part un calque de *football* (qui ne se prononce d'ailleurs pas [futbol] en [anglais](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/football)). Si on le lit comme un mot français, ça se lit [ɑ̃dbal] (comme une balle), si on le lit comme un mot allemand c'est [[hantbal]](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aDe-Handball.ogg).

Il n'y a donc aucune raison de prononcer [ɑ̃dbol], et le plus logique est de le prononcer à la française [ɑ̃dbal], qui a en plus le bon goût d'être proche de la prononciation d'origine. Si on veut couper les cheveux en quatre [ɑ̃dbol] a aussi le défaut de désigner le [handball gaélique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handball_ga%C3%A9lique) (quand on ne veut pas s'arracher la langue à prononcer [*liathróid láimhe*](https://ga.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liathr%C3%B3id_l%C3%A1imhe)) ou le [handball américain](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handball_am%C3%A9ricain), les deux se prononçant [[ˈhændˌbɔl]](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aen-us-handball.ogg) en anglais.

En ce qui concerne ceux qui te corrigent, j'imagine que le « c'est Allemand » veut surtout dire « c'est pas Anglais, c'est absurde de le prononcer comme si ça l'était ». Mais tu peux évidemment prononcer *handball* comme tu as envie que les autres l'entendent.

Dans le cas général, je suis assez partisan de prononcer les mots empruntés le plus proche possible de l'original : c'est plus marrant et ça permet de s'intéresser un peu à d'autres langues. Mais je n'en veux pas à ceux qui n'ont pas envie de faire l'effort.

Comment: Ce qui me chagrine c'est de créer des exceptions, cela m'emcombre le cerveau. Si ça s'écrit pareil, pourquoi ne pas le prononcer pareil ?

Comment: J'ai corrigé le hand-deux-balle en hand-balle, l'attardement sur le "d" étant plutôt de mon imagination.

Comment: @hoang Parce que ça a plus de sens ? Mais c'est juste par goût personnel, rien ne t'oblige.

Comment: On est pas sur *meta*, je ne suis pas d'accord, mais c'est une bonne réponse... +1 :) "Mais tu peux évidemment prononcer handball comme tu as envie que les autres l'entendent." Agreed !

Comment: Si le plus logique est de prononcer à la française, pourquoi ne dirait-on pas foot-balle ?

Comment: Parce que football est anglais, donc ça du sens d'essayer de le prononcer à l'anglaise. Handball n'est pas anglais, donc ça n'a pas de sens de le prononcer comme si ça l'était.

Comment: @hoang, il y a des gens en France qui disent "foot-balle" (sans doute peu, et qui ne font pas forcément partie des plus jeunes générations, peut-être).

Comment: @Bruno Effectivement, même moi pour déconner, en l'occurence personne ne me reprend en disant *C'est Foot-BAll, c'est anglais*. Je commence à me demander si la rigueur allemande n'aurait pas quelquechose à voir avec tout ça ...

Answer (score 6):

En général, la prononciation d'un mot discerné comme un emprunt est quelque part entre la prononciation originale et la prononciation naturellement déduite de l'orthographe suivant les règles du français. Pour *football*, d'origine anglaise, la prononciation /futbol/ est aussi proche de la prononciation originale que les phonèmes du français le permettent. Pour *handball*, d'origine allemande, la prononciation la plus proche est /andbal/ ; /ɑ̃dbal/ reste une bonne approximation. Déformer le /-bal/ en /-bol/ est pour le moins incongru : l'argument de la francisation ne tient pas, puisqu'on s'éloigne de l'import direct. La seule explication possible pour le suffixe /-bol/ est une contamination de l'anglais.

Là où le bât blesse est l'origine allemande de *handball*. Ce sont les circonstances historiques de son import en France qui font que bien que ce sport soit, comme beaucoup de -balls, d'origine Anglo-Saxonne sous sa forme moderne, il est s'est répandu en France [sous Vichy et l'Occupation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handball#Histoire).

Prononcer *handball* à l'anglaise est donc réécrire l'histoire. Une réécriture qui peut tout à fait paraître sympathique, au demeurant ; mais une réécriture que la plupart des gens qui prononcent ainsi ignorent.

Donc si tu tiens à prononcer *handball* /ɑ̃dbol/, ne dis pas « Est-ce que je t'emmerde avec paëlla ? » (qui est complètement à côté de la plaque), mais « j'emmerde le régime de Vichy ». Ou, si tu veux snober encore plus, prononce /ɔndbœld/ (approximation non garantie), puisque si la France a découvert ce sport via l'Allemagne, celle-ci l'avait à son tour importé du Danemark : c'est [là qu'on été fixée les règles du sport](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handball#Histoire), sous le nom danois *håndbold*.

Comment: Je préfère rester à coté de la plaque, puisque je n'ai aucune revendication politique ou éthique à prononcer comme cela. C'est une habitude de prononciation à laquelle je ne me fait pas. C'est comme faire répéter quelqu'un qui zozote, c'est juste mal placé.

Comment: Pourquoi suggères-tu la variation snob "/ɔndbœld/", peux-tu expliquer ? (même en disant que c'est non garanti :)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Ah, j'avais oublié de l'écrire dans la réponse. Parce que le mot vient du danois (via l'allemand).

Answer (score 2):

Ma prononciation est quelque chose comme [andbal] parce que c'est celle des pratiquants francophones de ce sport que je connais (et je ne parle guère de handball qu'avec eux).

Sur le problème plus général de la prononciation des mots étrangers, au début de leur adoption, une prononciation proche de la prononciation d'origine mais adaptée à la phonétique française me semble le meilleur choix. Mais plus le mot rentre dans la langue, plus sa prononciation va devenir indépendante de son origine, avec des variations causées par l'orthographe, par la méconnaissance de la prononciation correcte malgré un désir de s'en approcher, par la proximité d'autres mots importés, et il arrive un moment où s'attacher trop à l'origine devient pédant.

Dans les cas de handball, l'usage me semble encore hésiter.

Answer (score 1):

Je me faisais la même réflexion. Pour apporter de l'eau à ton moulin, j'espère que tous les handbâââlleurs prononcent bien kaLaté et non karaté, Jioudo et non Judo, kamikazé et non kamikaz', etc etc.
Si je poussais le bouchon, si on voulait vraiment respecter le pays d'origine, on ne dirait même pas football, mais soccer, ce qui éviterait les confusions inutiles

Comment: Complètement d'accord avec tes exemples de mots importés. Par contre, je ne suis du tout d'accord au sujet du football... le pays d'origine du football est l'Angleterre qui utilise bien « football ». Le soccer est le nom donné par les américains au « football » historique parce qu'eux appellent « football » le football américain. (cf http://i2.wp.com/www.irkitated.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/original.jpg )

Comment: Très bon exemples tirés du Japonais d'autant plus que je suis d'origine asiatique et qu'à la lecture je me sens obligé de prendre l'accent caricatural qu'on attribue à tous les asiatiques. Ca me fera de très bons exemples avec une touche d'humour :)

Answer (score 0):

> Si vous avez d'autres exemples de mots qui respectent ou ne respectent
>   pas leur langue d'origine, je suis preneur.

"*Suspense*" est plus souvent prononcé "suce-peine-ce" que "ceux-ce-peine-ce" (à l'anglaise).

Answer (score 0):

Il existe le même débat quant au mot *iceberg*. Certains disent *aice* et d'autres (ceux qui ont raison) disent *isse*. L'erreur est de considérer que l'origine du mot est anglaise et donc d'appliquer un accent anglais à ce mot, tout comme pour le *bale* de handball quand on utilise *bole*, à tort

Comment: L'orthographe *iceberg* vient clairement de l'anglais. Quant à la prononciation, je ne vois pas de raison de le prononcer autrement. Le néerlandais m'a l'air [tout à fait similaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ijsberg#nl).