# « Venezuela » (sans accents) mais « vénézuéliens » (avec accents) ?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques

Je suis récemment tombé sur une règle orthographique qui m'a étonné.

Visiblement en français, nous devons écrire « Venezuela » sans les accents aigûs sur les *e* lorsque l'on parle du pays mais lorsque l'on parle des individus y vivant, nous devons écrire « vénézuéliens » avec les accents aigus sur les *e*.

Existe-t-il une raison à cette règle ?

Comment: Pour le problème plus général, voir la question [Qui détermine l'orthographe et la prononciation des noms propres étrangers ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/605/qui-determine-lorthographe-et-la-prononciation-des-noms-propres-etrangers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La [commission nationale de toponymie](http://www.cnig.gouv.fr/Front/docs/cms/cntpvm_enrichi_13avril2010_127540209260628000.pdf) admet les deux orthographes, « Vénézuéla » et « Venezuela ».

Il s'agit d'un cas où le nom local et le nom francisé ne diffèrent que par les accents ce qui doit aider à maintenir le nom local en français malgré l'usage prédominant ailleurs d'utiliser des noms de pays francisés (bien que plus le pays est récent, moins cet usage domine). Mais sauf à être dans la logique où il faut appeler l'Angleterre « England » ou orthographier *Viêt Nam* « Việt Nam » refuser comme incorrects les accents me semble excessivement pédant.

Comment: Sauf erreur de ma part, cela n'explique pas pourquoi en français, on n'utilise pas le terme « Vénézuéla ». En français, on dit bien « Arménie » et non « Armenia ».

Comment: L'objectif de ma réponse était d'infirmer l'affirmation comme quoi en français, on n'utilisait pas le terme « Vénézuéla » et de proposer une tentative d'explication au fait que « Venezuela » est aussi utilisé.   J'ai essayé de clarifier.

Comment: @Zistoloen Arménie est un terme avec une tradition latine très ancienne et qui contient le suffixe très commun -ie. Des noms de pays plus comparables seraient d'autres d'Amérique du Sud comme Colombie (contient le suffixe -ia en espagnol donc facilement traduisible en -ie), Brésil (nommé d'après le bois de brésil, un dérivé de braise), Argentine (avec le suffixe -ina en ES donc -ine en FR). Les noms de pays provenant des langues indigènes ou dont l'étymologie est peu claire ne sont pas adaptés, ou ne le sont que pour respecter la phonétique: Guatemala, Uruguay, Pérou

Comment: Vénézuéla est d'origine romane mais elle est obscure et aucun francophone ne devinerait que c'est un diminutif de Venise

Comment: Je pense que ça surprend parfois les locuteurs des autres langues romanes que des mots en -a soient empruntés tels quels en français alors que pendant très longtemps ils auraient reçu un -e muet, gardant ainsi l'accent tonique sur la bonne syllabe. Mais les francophones ont arrêté de faire ça au 19e siècle, quand la graphie a pris la main sur la prononciation. On a depuis pris l'habitude d'emprunter les mots des autres langues romanes en les modifiant moins, et tant pis pour l'accent

Comment: La seule exception sont lorsque les langues rentre en contact dans un contexte strictement oral, comme dans les communautés d'immigrants italiens en Belgique. Là des emprunts comme qué scarogne, ricotte, mozarelle ou mïngue abondent

Answer (score 2):

*Venezuela* est le nom dans la langue locale et a été conservé tel quel (mais *Vénézuéla* est aussi admis), contrairement à d'autres pays dont le nom aura été francisé (*Colombia* devenant *Colombie*, *Ecuador* devenant *Équateur*, etc...).

Comment: Ok mais pourquoi le terme « Venezuela » a été conservé tel quel et n'a pas été francisé (ajout d'accents notamment) ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas la réponse exacte pour le cas du Vénézuéla, mais tu trouveras qlq pistes [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/656/1129).

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que cela vient du fait que le nom du pays est un nom **propre** et respecte l'orthographe native du nom et que les habitants (ici les vénézuéliens) est un nom **commun** et donc respecte les conventions d'orthographe de la langue française

Comment: Ok mais pourquoi en français, on utilise le terme « Venezuela » (sans accents) et non « Vénézuéla » (avec accents) ?

Comment: Autant pour moi, on peut utiliser les 2 orthographes en français, celle native et celle francisée