# Prononciation de mots scientifiques et noms propres

Tags: noms-propres, science

Je voudrais savoir comment on doit prononcer les noms propres et surtout les mots scientifiques.

J'ai souvent entendu les francophones prononcent un mot comme *thread* :

- sread

ou

- tread

Parfois on est obligé de prononcer des mots chinois ou japonnais d'une manière bizarre et différente de l'original, mais dans le cas de langues qui sont un peu proches comme l'anglais et le français, je ne comprends pas cette différence de prononciation.

Donc ma question est : Dans le cas ou on peut prononcer le mot correctement , est ce qu'on doit:

1. le prononcer dans la langue d'origine
2. le prononcer dans notre langue maternelle

Comment: Tu trouveras des éléments de réponse ici : [Qui détermine l'orthographe et la prononciation des noms propres étrangers?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/605/qui-d%c3%a9termine-lorthographe-et-la-prononciation-des-noms-propres-%c3%a9trangers)

Comment: Le français et l'anglais ne sont pas du tout considérées comme des langues "proches" en ce qui concerne la prononciation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les Français prononcent les mots anglais à la française. C'est l'usage, et je dirais que ça donne une impression snob de ne pas suivre cet usage.

Les autres francophones prononcent à l'anglaise au contraire (les Belges je suis sûr, les Québécois je crois, les Suisses je ne sais pas.)

Mais il y a différentes façons de franciser ces mots, et il n'y a pas de règles. 'srède' et 'trède' est un bon exemple; pour les noms propres, il est intéressant d'entendre différents journalistes dire Angela Merkel ou Jean-Claude Juncker (Anjèla / Anguèla, Merkeul / Merkèle, Younkeur / Djeunkeur)

Comment: Je confirme pour les **Québécois** (prononce à l'anglaise).

Comment: @Sifu Pardon, j'ai corrigé Canadiens -> Québécois

Comment: Merci :). Canada réfère habituellement pour le Canada anglophone. Tandis-que Québec réfère pour le Canada francophone.

Comment: La prononciation francisée (et ça ne concerne pas que l'anglais, bien sûr)  elle est la règle sauf à restituer la prononciation originale très exactement. Voir (enfin, plutôt écouter) la réponse du médiateur à ce sujet sur France Info le [13 juin 2014](http://www.franceinfo.fr/emission/le-rendez-vous-du-mediateur/2013-2014/de-sao-paulo-san-paolo-06-13-2014-13-15).